# How to use filter-collections with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, filter

I'm trying to use the package doctorpangloss:filter-collections in my project.

What I have now is the following:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('locations', function() {
  return Locations.find();
});
```

Router:

```
this.route('foci', {
  path: '/foci',
(...)
},
waitOn : function () {
   return Meteor.subscribe('locations');
 }
});
```

Client:

```
----.html file----
<template name="foci">
<div class="row">
{{> LocationList}}
</div>
</template>

<template name="LocationList">
    {{#each locationData}}
    (...)
    {{/each}}
</template>

----.js file----
Template.LocationList.helpers({

    locationData: function(){
        return Locations.find()
    }
});
```

Everything standard till now. On the /foci page the data is displayed.
But I would like to have a list (or actually not a list, but tiles, but thats irrelevant here) that I can filter. I've tried my best with this package, but nothing worked. Based on the documentation ( https://github.com/workpop/filter-collections/ ) it should be a few minutes work to get it done, yet I've spent way more on trying to figure it out.

If anyone could help adding the standard filter bar to the page, or knows of another similar package I could use it would be appreciated.